# Merge duplicate tags?

Tags: discussion

Can someone merge the two tags [canon-m] and [canon-eos-m]. I see tag synonyms, which I've never used, but that requires a score of 5 on the tag which I do not have. Not sure if a mod can just do this.

**This is my argument for keeping the [canon-m] tag**:

Our other Canon DSLR tags which are also EOS cameras just use the format [canon-5d], [canon-60d], [canon-5d-mark-iii]. They leave out the "EOS" piece and just call use [Brand-Model].

Answer (score 2):

Done. I've kept the `[canon-m]` tag and made `[canon-eos-m]` a synonym of the former. Once more models of this type of camera appear, we might want to reshuffle things again, but for now I think this one tag will be sufficient.